# Can anyone suggest how to generate colors for heatmap

Tags: gradient, rgb

The Idea is I want to generate a heatmap using some data. The values of the data may be from 0 to 100.
I want to assign color in the following way:

```
0: Red , 50: Yellow, 100: Green
```

That means the color will be gradually go from red..yellow..to green like gradient of 3 colors.
Previously I was using

```
R = (255 * (20 - i)) / 20;
    G = (255 * i) / 20; 
    B = 0;
```

For gradient of Red and Green color. Can anyone suggest me how to include yellow in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t understand why division by 20 is there.

I would do the following.

Put red (R) at full strength in beginning. Gradually increase green (G) to Max till 50. From there keep green at full and reduce red gradually

```
if( i <= 50)
{
    R = 255;              //at full strength
    G = (i / 50.0) * 255; //increase G gradually 
}
else
{
    R = 255 - ((i - 50) / 50.0) * 255;   //decrease gradually
    G = 255;                       //at full strength
}

B = 0;
```

Thus max strength of R and G will be at middle. And towards left Red will be prominent and towards right Green will be prominent

Comment: for i=50 it will give R=127 G= 128 which is not yellow. But Can I get R=255 and G=255 at i=50?

Comment: @MdJohirulIslam My bad. Its fixed now

Comment: Slight correction I found R = ((i - 50) / 50.0) * 255; should be R = 255-((i - 50) / 50.0) * 255. Isn't it?

Comment: @MdJohirulIslam yes you are right. I added the correction

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to go red -> yellow -> green, lets take the RGB colours of those:

```
         R  G  B
================
Red:    FF 00 00
Yellow: FF FF 00
Green:  00 FF 00
```

So you can see that for the first half (i.e. 0 to 50) you just need to slowly increase the amount of green. Then for 50 to 100, slowly decrease the amount of red.

So a simple algorithm would be:

```
if n <= 50:
    R = 255
    G = n * (255/50)
    B = 0
else
    R = 255 - ((n-50) * (255/50))
    G = 255
    B = 0
```

We can convert this to Javascript like this:

```js
$('#percentage').on('change', function() {
  showColour();
});

function showColour() {
  var percentage = parseInt($('#percentage').val());
  var r, g, b;

  if (percentage <= 50) {
    r = 255;
    g = parseInt(percentage * (255 / 50));
    b = 0
  } else {
    percentage = percentage - 50;
    r = 255 - parseInt((percentage * (255 / 50)));
    g = 255;
    b = 0;
  }

  var newColour = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
  $('#colour-test').css('background-color', newColour);
}
showColour();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="percentage" value="0">
<div id="colour-test">This will change</div>
```